# Get a MenuItem to switch to a different visible window when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, menuitem

I am working with C# in MS Visual Studio Community 2013.  I am trying to set up a MenuItem so that when clicked it causes the current window to hide itself and another window appears at the same location.

I have a couple of books on the subject and I've also spent lots of time searching for answers online.  However, I simply can't find out how to set this up when it's something that should be relatively straightforward to do.

I've done it before with older versions of C#, but it just seems impossible to sort out with Visual Studio Community 2013.

At this stage I have a menu and menu items set up something like the 'much simplified' following:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1264" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="14">
    <MenuItem Header="Item Type" Margin="0" Width="100" Height="21" FontSize="11" Click="MenuItem_Click">
        <MenuItem Header="Item Action" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="185"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Most, if not all of that was generated automatically, as I set up the menu in Visual Studio.

Also, if I right click on the 'Item Action' menu item, a popup appears with a 'view code' option.  If I click that option, the following empty function appears in the corresponding *.cs file:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }
```

I realise that I probably need to add code to that empty method to do what I need to do, but so far I haven't found out how to do that.

There is also a 'Command' property in the properties list for the MenuItem.  I also assume that that may play a part in sorting this out, but at this stage I don't know how.

Please let me know how this needs to be set up and big thanks in advance for any help.

Also, after searching elsewhere on stackoverflow, I found the basics for hiding/showing different windows.  I've got that working OK, but it's not enough to resolve my problem.

Basically, in my real menu I have multiple menuItems and the clicking of each one needs to be dealt with in a different way.  Therefore, in the MenuItem_Click function I need a way of identifying which MenuItem was actually clicked, so that I can respond in the correct way for each and every MenuItem click.

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event for each menu item and add code for each method.inside this method you can add this code

```
Window1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
window2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

you can use Command property when you need to bind methods in MVVM Pattern

Comment: Like I said at the end of my original question, I've already found how to control visibility.  I'm using xxxxWindow.Show(); and yyyyWindow.Hide();.

Comment: My problem is that I want to do different things in the code for each MenuItem click and at this stage all of the menuItems in my menu just get the same code applied to them when clicked.

Comment: I just want to write a separate piece of code for each MenuItem click and so far that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Create another method and change the name of this method and the code inside it and keep the parameter then go to xaml file and change click event property value and use the new name of new method

Comment: Yes 'thank you' that's solved the problem - 100%.   It's very straightforward when you see the solution.  Thanks to you I've now seen it.